# convert the unicode datetime to django datetime parse datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, unicode

I am getting the datetime from jquery in the format 2014/11/27 22:00
and type of this date is

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

i want to convert this to django datetime format 
i am using

```
dateparse.parse_date(date)
```

But getting result None

Code:

```
date = request.POST['date'] 
print date
print type(date)
finaldate = dateparse.parse_date(date)
print finaldate
```

using

```
finaldate = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
```

i am getting the proper datetime and getting saved also , but while displaying that datetime date is getting displayed properlly but time is not getting proper, time is getting displayed 5 hours later
like when i select the time 17:00 its getting saved as 17:00 but while displaying it displays 11:30 and throwing the runtime error also

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2014-11-28 17:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
```

I dont know what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 

finaldate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Its not working and not throwing any errors also  [17/Nov/2014 15:11:19] "POST /cbs/update_create_record/ HTTP/1.1" 500 14051

Comment: Some debug info to find out what lines of code throw error. Try to run this command in console if you doesn't know how to switch on debug mode in your framework.